# operation not permitted on isolatedstoragefilestream all the time

Tags: windows-phone-8

there was a lot of question about this error, but i couldn't find the problem i'm facing with it.

I have 2 buttons: 1 to save some string into the isolatedStorage, and 1 to read it.

when i try to read it i get the errorMessage written in the title.

Button1.Click is:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("kedvencek" + ".txt",
                System.IO.FileMode.Append,
                System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                store))
            {
                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
                writer.WriteLine("something");
                writer.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }
```

and the Button 2:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
            using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("kedvencek" + ".txt",
                System.IO.FileMode.Open,
                System.IO.FileAccess.ReadWrite,
                store))
            {
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
                string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(text);
                sr.Close();
                stream.Close();

            }
```

Comment: Any difference, if you use the StreamWriter and StreamReader in a using() as well?

Comment: i tried in several ways, and still get that error message, in a new project a bit different code works, and when i copy it into this one it shows the error message again :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is connected with the fact that [as MSDN says:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> FileMode.Append can only be used in conjunction with Write.

So it will work if you had changed it to:

```
using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("kedvencek" + ".txt",
            FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, store))
```

On the other hand you don't need to close `stream` when you have it in `using()`, after leaving `using()` the steream is Disposed automatically. And it will better to put `StreamWriter` also into `using()`:

```
private void first_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("kedvencek" + ".txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, store))
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("something");
    }
}

private void second_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("kedvencek" + ".txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, store))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
}
```